# Optimize Network For UDP Broadcast Traffic?

Tags: ieee-802.11, udp, broadcast

I have a computer that creates an AP which multiple microcontrollers connect to. The computer sends out UDP Broadcast packets that tell the microcontrollers to do different things.

I have an issue where the packets are being received by the microcontrollers out of sync, meaning the computer is sending the packets at a very consistent interval, but on the receiving end, the packets are being received with the time between them compressing and expanding every so many packets. This only happens when there are lower times between packets being sent (usually around 0.5 seconds or less).

I have confirmed that this issue is being caused by the network, and not the microcontrollers decoding the packets. Are there any ways I can optimize a 2.4gHz WiFi network to decrease these inconsistencies with the timing?

Comment: It’s not the network if you have one AP. You send a broadcast and everyone hears the packet at the same time. Your problem is elsewhere. Removed off topic devices.

Comment: The only thing that could affect the transmission is other devices on that channel. Try a less used one.

Comment: Unfortunately, your question is too broad to answer as asked. Please include things like a good network description or diagram, the network device models, the network device configurations, any logs, debugs, etc. Remember that hosts/servers are off-topic here, as are consumer-grade devices.

Comment: Wireless networks aren't really deterministic since they're influenced by channel arbitration, concurrent networks on the same and adjacent channels, and by other applications using the same band. If you need more precision you need to either use a dedicated band or a wired network.

Comment: how do you confirm that packets are sent out in consistent intervals?

Comment: Can you measure whether all receivers of different types (wifi hardware) perceive the same broadcast reception jitter?  It's possible your problem is induced by the transmitter -- but just as possible that it's the receiver.  To figure this out, I would sync the clocks of multiple receivers and use e.g. `tcpdump` to determine if some receiving stations perceive jitter on certain packets when others do not.  Add some hardware & OS diversity for a useful comparison.